# OpenShift Online 3 Cannot find application source nor maven in S2I scripts

Tags: java, maven, openshift

I'm trying to setup a custom build for an OpenShift Online 3 application, following the [instructions for S2I scripts](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/creating_images/s2i.html#s2i-scripts). I tried this with both an application based on the OpenJDK catalog template, and one based on the Red Hat JBoss Web Server (Tomcat) catalog template.

My `assemble` and `run` scripts are recognized during the build, however I couldn't find either the application artifacts directory, nor the application source one, from inside `assemble`. In the example script they are located at `/tmp/s2i/artifacts` and `/tmp/s2i/src`, but in my case those directories don't exist. [The documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/creating_images/s2i.html) says that

> Before executing the assemble script, S2I untars that file and places its contents into the location specified with the --destination flag or the io.openshift.s2i.destination label from the builder image, with the default location being the /tmp directory.

but I have no idea where that `--destination` flag or `io.openshift.s2i.destionation` label are defined. Also, I tried to `ls -la` the `/tmp` directory from the `assemble` script, and I could only find an empty `/tmp/src` directory.

In addition to this, my `assemble` script tries to build the project with Maven: however, the `mvn` command cannot be found. I tried to log into the pod, and `mvn` cannot be found there either. However, when I make a new build without any custom scripts, and watch the build logs, I can see that it's indeed running Maven:

```
Found pom.xml... attempting to build with 'mvn -e -Popenshift -DskipTests -Dcom.redhat.xpaas.repo.redhatga package --batch-mode -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true '
```

So where can I find the source location, and the `mvn` executable from the `assemble` script?

Comment: What do you have in your custom ``assemble`` script? An artifacts directory will only exist if incremental builds are enabled. Plus most S2I builders use ``/tmp/artifacts`` and ``/tmp/src`` directory, although they can override configuration and use different locations. All the same, if you run the original ``assemble`` script before your actions, the contents of those may already have been moved elsewhere. What is the actual name of the S2I builder being used so can look to see how they are configured.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thanks for your reply. How do I know if I'm running the original `assemble` script? I've just added my own under `.s2i/bin/` in the project source. Where can I find the name of the S2I builder? Running `oc describe bc` I got `From Image:     ImageStreamTag openshift/redhat-openjdk18-openshift:1.1`: is this what you are referring to?

Comment: You would be running the original if you ran it from your own ``assemble`` script. If you do not call the original, then you need to be replicating all it does. This is why I asked what you had in your ``assemble`` script.

Comment: I'm not calling any other script from my `assemble`. It actually is still very simple because I'm still trying to understand how the thing works. However, I'll be downloading Jetty and unpack/configure it, and then I'll be building the project using Maven, to prepare for the `run` script that will launch the application over Jetty.

Comment: So you don't want to customise the existing S2I builder, but implement your own from scratch? If you want a simple example of a builder to look at see https://github.com/getwarped/s2i-httpd-server for one that starts from scratch, and https://github.com/openshift-katacoda/simple-http-server for one that uses an existing S2I builder as a base by replaces the existing ``assemble`` and ``run`` scripts.

Comment: FWIW, for ``openshift/redhat-openjdk18-openshift`` the existing S2I scripts are under ``/usr/local/s2i``. So if you were going to run the existing ``assemble`` script and then run your own actions, you would need to run ``/usr/local/s2i/assemble`` first. According to the ``s2i-setup`` script in that directory, looks like ``assemble`` does expect files to be in ``/tmp/src``.

Comment: If you want to dig around inside of the image, use ``oc describe is/redhat-openjdk18-openshift`` to find out image registry reference for the image version, and then run something like:  ``oc run test --restart=Never --image=registry.access.redhat.com/redhat-openjdk-18/openjdk18-openshift@sha256:d65d37ccf9417781ae99e1a17aedc42f76b20d6162094d4053d499f395e1d943 --command /bin/bash -t -i`` to start it and get shell. Change to ``/usr/local/s2i`` to look at existing files.

Comment: When done, run ``oc delete pod/test`` to clean up temporary pod.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thanks again for your extensive instructions! I found the original scripts at `/usr/local/s2i` and studied them to understand how to prepare the assemble script, which you can check at https://github.com/michelezamuner/jgroph/blob/os-test-build/.s2i/bin/assemble. Builds themselves are now successful, however, it has been impossible to make any successful deploy because the container continuously crashes. I tried more than a dozen times, also waiting some hours in between, but it always failed, thus leading me to think that there's still some problem with my build.

Comment: For a failing deployment, run ``oc debug dc/yourappname``. It will start up the image but start an interactive shell for you. You can then dig around in it to see what is there and run the ``run`` script manually. If you need to send it requests, use ``oc rsh`` to get into the pod from another window and use curl against ``localhost:8080``.

Comment: When I log in the debug pod, I cannot do pretty much anything with my user, not even `cd` into `$HOME` (permission denied). Of course also trying to run `assemble` fails for the same reason. Is there something wrong I'm doing or is this expected?

Comment: You likely aren't fixing up file system permissions correctly then. The container is run as an arbitrary user and file system permissions must be adjusted to cope with that. Are you using the guidelines at https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/creating_images/guidelines.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think you're referring to the "Support Arbitrary User IDs" section: however, I have no idea how I can run those commands...I am not creating a custom image, just putting `assemble` and `run` scripts inside the `.s2i` directory in my project. Maybe it's simply impossible to do what I'm trying to, and I should just stick with the preset images coming with OpenShift (for example switching from Jetty to Tomcat using the Red Hat JBoss Web Server image)?